# Call parameters of a menu in a module in joomla3 with k2

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

I want to get parameters of a specific menu in joomla3/k2

I can get current menu by this code:

```
$params = K2HelperUtilities::getParams('com_k2');

$_myparam=$params->get('menu-meta_url');
```

Now how can I call $params->get('menu-meta_url') form another page or module?!

Comment: Try making the variable global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - if you just want to get the current menu params... you can use the default.

```
  $itemid = JRequest::getVar('Itemid');
  $menu = &JSite::getMenu();
  $active = $menu->getItem($itemid);
  $params = $menu->getParams( $active->id );
```

Comment: `JRequest` and `JSite::getMenu` should not be used on Joomla 3.x